# JComboBox getSelectedIndex() method always return 0

Tags: java, swing, sqlite, arraylist, jcombobox

I run into an issue with my code, and i can't figure it out.

What i'm trying to do is populate the jComboBox with data from SQLlite and then get index of selected item so i could use it for further activities.
I'm populating jComboBox using array list.

And here is the code for array list:

```
public ArrayList<Battery> batteries() throws Exception {
    ArrayList<Battery> batteriesList = new ArrayList();
    try {
        Statement stmt = null;
        Connection conn = null;
        Battery currentBattery = null;
        String url = "jdbc:sqlite:batteries.db";
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        String sql = "Select * from batteries";
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        while (rs.next()) {
            currentBattery = new Battery(rs.getString("companyName"), rs.getString("batteryType"), rs.getFloat("batteryVolt"), rs.getFloat("batteryAmp"));
            batteriesList.add(currentBattery);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
    return batteriesList;
}
```

Here is my code for populating jComboBox:

```
public void showBatteries() {
    ArrayList<Battery> list = null;
    try {
        list = batteries();
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            jComboBox_BatteryChooser.addItem(list.get(i).getCompanyName() + " " + list.get(i).getBatteryModel());
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(mainWindow.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
```

To get the index of selected item i'm using this:

```
public void fillData(){
 System.out.println("Index of item: "+jComboBox_BatteryChooser.getSelectedIndex());
}
```

However all the time the result of function fillData() is always 0.
Could you point me to correct direction or help me solve this issue?
Thank you very much :)

Comment: At what time do you call fillData? Are you shure, that there is an item selected at this time? Did you select one and then call the method?

Comment: I'm calling in fillData in here: 

`private void jComboBox_BatteryChooserActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                         
fillData();
    }`

Comment: hm that doesn't tell me much. Is this in some kind of a listener on the JComboBox?

Comment: I'm relatively new into programming so i will tell everything i've done maybe. I'm using Netbeans for my Java programming. I created new jframe form with name MainWindow and arranged it how i wanted it to be (jComboBox is on jPanel3, still in class MainWindow). After placing jComboBox i clicked it  twice and it created this:
   
private void jComboBox_BatteryChooserActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                         
    }  

so i thought that that's the area where i should insert my code.

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).